# Implementing @Before/@Post something with Spring AOP

Tags: spring, annotations, aop, spring-aop

I need to intercept all the methods of type writer.write(myObj) , and if and only if myObj contains a method annotated with @BeforeWrite, execute this method.

I am kind of confused because I can intercept a method call on the writer, but I don't know how to provide a pointcut that looks if there is a method annotated with @BeforeWriter, this looks similar to how probably a @PostLoad annotation is handled in JPA...

Answer (score 1):

In your interceptor handling method you have the argument of type `ProceedingJoinPoint`, which has method `getArgs()`. You can check your argument (`myObj`) methods reflections and make your decision whether to proceed. Example (`call` is of type `ProceedingJoinPoint`):

```
boolean proceed = false;
for (Method method : call.getArgs()[0].getClass().getMethods()) {
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(BeforeWriter.class)) {
        proceed = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, I have to loop on the methods to verify if it exists... right?

Comment: If you don't like looping on collections and prefer predicative approach, try out [Apache collection util](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html).